# Properties of Logarithm (what is wrong with my math?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The question is to find the intersection point between $y = log_22x$ and $y = log_4x$

So my first instinct was to make the same base 2. (Since 4 = 2 + 2)

$log_22x = log_4x$

$log_22 + log_2x = log_4x$

$1 + log_2x = log_4x$

$1 +\frac{1}{log_x2} = \frac{1}{log_x4}$

$1 +\frac{1}{log_x2} = \frac{1}{log_x2 + log_x2}$

Let y = $log_x2$

$1 + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{y+y}$

$\frac{y+1}{y} = \frac{1}{y+y}$

Cross multiply

$(y+1)(y+y) = (y)(1)$

$2y^2 + 2y = y$

$2y^2 + y = 0$

$y(2y + 1) = 0$

$y = 0$ or $y =-1/2$ (won't work since argument has to be greater than 0)

What is wrong with my math???

How would you tackle this problem? Your instinct? (I want to know various ways to tackle this problem because I gave up on the first one but got it right using this one:

$log_22x = log_4x$

$4^{log_22x} = x$

$2^{log_22x} * 2^{log_22x} = x$

$2x * 2x = x$

$4x^{2} - x = 0$

$x = 0, x= 1/4$

x = 1/4 is the right answer

THIS IS PRE-CALCULUS QUESTION (Please explain at a pre-cal level Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, your first method is perfectly correct! There's no reason to discard the $y=-\frac12$ answer because $y$ is not the argument of a logarithm (so needs not be positive). Remembering that $y=\log_x2$, we compute $x$:

$$-\frac12 = \log_x2$$
$$x^{-\frac12} = 2$$
$$x = (x^{-\frac12})^{-2} = 2^{-2} = \frac14$$
which matches the answer you got from the other method.

Comment: ...lol what??? I am actually so dumb, I have been trying this problem for like an hour to get it right.. thanks.! BTW, how would you attempt this question if you were to solve it?

Comment: @KeKe My instinct would be like the second method you mentioned -- for whatever reason, my gut tells me to get rid of the logarithms (via exponentiation) as quickly as possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks! @Y. Forman

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong, but…

In general, $\log_a(x)=\dfrac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(a)}$. Indeed, if $y=\log_a(x)$, then $x=a^y$ and therefore $\log_b(x)=y\log_b(a)$. Thus
$$
\log_a(x)=y=\dfrac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(a)}
$$

With this at hand, the equation
$$
\log_2(2x)=\log_4(x)
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
\log_2(2x)=\frac{\log_2(x)}{\log_2(4)}
$$
that, using $\log_2(4)=2$, simplifies to $2\log_2(2x)=\log_2(4)$, that is,
$$
\log_2(4x^2)=\log_2(x)
$$
This forces $4x^2=x$ and, being $x>0$ by assumption, $x=1/4$.

Comment: I understand the formula but can you explain how log4(x) becomes log2(x)/log2(4) with a base of two? Why is it two? Thank you @egreg

Comment: @KeKe Use the base change formula with $a=4$ and $b=2$. Why choosing $b=2$? Because on the left hand side you have $\log_2(2x)$ and $\log_2(4)$ is easy.

Comment: @Ok, so b can be any number but in this case you used 2 to match the base with te other log? Because log3(x)/log3(4) still produces log4x

Comment: @KeKe Yes, but the idea is to get all logarithms in the expression to be in the same base.

Answer (score 0):

You did nothing wrong, except you did not finish. $y=-1/2$ means $\log_x 2=-1/2$ or $\log_2 x=-2$ or $x=1/4$